# pip[3] command not found even though pip is installed

Tags: python, pip

I want to run this script:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

However, when I run it I get the error message

```
-bash: pip3: command not found
```

I have already installed brew and pip. When I run

```
pip3 -V
```

I get `pip 19.0.3` from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Does anybody know why I am getting that error message?

If it helps, I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/freeezer98/export-archive-reddit-saved/blob/master/README.md) program in the end

Comment: You run it with the []?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this command, if you are woring on python3.

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

from you error code it looks like you are running pip[3] , which is wrong.

for python2, you can run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

pip is for python2 version.
pip3 is for python3 version you should install python3 interpreter for pip3 and provide in environment variables.